# How can I delete first and last characters of strings using member functions of std::string, without using remove_if, erase, etc?

Tags: c++, string

EDIT: This question had been solved as of 1 PM on October 10, 2020. Thank you!

I was wondering how to remove the first and last special characters of a string variable "words", without touching the special characters in the middle and using remove, and erase-remove_if idioms. For example, the string @**Case-closed*!! should return Case-closed, but the internal special characters must not be touched.

Specifically, I want to make use of find_first_of, find_last_of, length() [equivalent to size()]. Here is my attempted code but I am unsure how to go about setting the boolean condition for the for loop (or while loop). The code below is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    const string charsToSearchFor = "!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:;\"\'`<>,.\?/|\\";
    string words = "@**Man_Of_Steel...!";
    string forDisplay;
    
    int length = static_cast<int>(words.length()) - 1;
    cout<<"The string is "<<length<<" characters long."<<endl;
    
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    bool foundOnFirst((int)words.find_first_of(charsToSearchFor) == 0);
    bool foundOnLast((int)words.find_last_of(charsToSearchFor) == length);
    bool isAlphabet((words[length] >= 'A' && words[length] <= 'Z') || (words[length] >= 'a' && words[length] <= 'z' ));
    
    cout<<"The first instance was found on "
        <<(int)words.find_first_of(charsToSearchFor)
        <<endl;
    cout<<"The last instance was found on "
        <<(int)words.find_last_of(charsToSearchFor)
        <<endl;
        
    cout<<"The boolean variable foundOnFirst should be true; actually it is: "
        <<foundOnFirst
        <<endl;
    cout<<"The boolean variable foundOnLast should be true; actually it is: "
        <<foundOnLast
        <<endl;    
    
    cout<<"This should be one; returns: "<<foundOnFirst<<std::endl;
    cout<<"This should be one; returns: "<<foundOnLast<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    //for deleting the first few special characters of a string; I have no clue
    //what Boolean condition would go into the second part of the for loop
    if (!isAlphabet || foundOnLast) {
        for (length = words.length(); !isAlphabet; length--) {
            //forDisplay = words.substr(1, length + 1);
            cout<<"The word in the loop process is: "<<forDisplay<<endl;
            cout<<"The length currently is: "<<length<<endl;                
            forDisplay = words.substr(1, length + 1);
            count2++;
        }//end if
    }
    
    //for deleting the last few special characters of a string; again, I have no
    //idea what Boolean condition would go into the second part of the for loop
    if (!isAlphabet || foundOnLast) {
        for (length = words.length(); !isAlphabet; length--) {
            //forDisplay = words.substr(1, length + 1);
            cout<<"The word in the loop process is: "<<forDisplay<<endl;
            cout<<"The length currently is: "<<length<<endl;                
            forDisplay = words.substr(1, length + 1);
            count2++;
        }//end if
    }
    
    cout<<"The word without the special characters is "<<forDisplay<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What would be your advice? Many thanks.

Comment: You already  have `charsToSearchFor`. Use `find_first_not_of`, `find_last_not_of`, and `substr`, and you won't need any loops at all.

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't remove anything, even though your questions states you want to delete characters.  All it does is create a new string from the existing string.  By what means were you going to erase characters if you can't use `erase` in some way?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the comment. I should have clarified. By "deleting" I meant creating new versions of strings that have characters removed from each end if they contain special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `find_first_of` with `find_first_not_of` to delete the first special characters, and combines `find_last_of` with `find_last_not_of` to delete the last special characters.

Or if you want to delete until alphabet characters you can do one loop to search for the first and last alphabet characters, and `substr` that range.

Either way, maybe consider using 1 criteria only, alphabet, or blacklist

Answer (score 1):

you can solve your problem with substr function just like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "substring";
    string d = s.substr(1,s.size()-2);
    cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

the first parameter is the index that you want to start with and the second one is the lenght of the new string so here the new string begins from the second letter in s and it takes (size of s)-2
so the output is "ubstrin"
I hope that was useful

good luck!